# How to deal with longitudinal symptom data in R using lag/lead and ifelse/case_when (or other solution)?

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi stack overflow community,

I'm relatively new to R (9 months) and this is my first stack overflow question with reprex and would really appreciate any help. I mainly use tidyverse although I am open to base R solutions.

Problem:

I have ~21,000 rows of symptom data with >10 variables per day. I would like to be able to classify "exacerbations" of a disease (in this case chest infections in lung disease) by using rules to define the start and end of the episode so that I can later calculate duration of episodes, type of episode (this depends on the combination of symptoms) and treatment received. As with any data set involving patients there are missing values. I have imputed from the most recent day if less than 2 days of data is missing.

The below code is a simplified, made up example involving only 1 symptom.

Exacerbation Rule: 
Start of exacerbation = 2 days of worse symptoms (>= 3)
Resolution of exacerbation = 5 days with normal breathing (<=2)

I would ideally want to be able to identify all days when an exacerbation is happening too.

Here is the data:

```
#load packages
library(tidyverse)

#load data

id <- "A"

day <- c(1:50)

symptom <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,3,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2)


df <- data.frame(id,day,symptom)

#Data Dictionary
#Symptom: 1 = Better than usual, 2 = Normal/usual, 3 = Worse than usual, 4 = Much worse than usual
```

What I have tried:

I have tried to approach this by using a combination of lag() and lead() with conditional statements case_when() and ifelse().

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars("symptom"), #used for more variables within vars() argument
            .funs = list(lead1 = ~ lead(., n = 1),
                         lead2 = ~ lead(., n = 2),
                         lead3 = ~ lead(., n = 3),
                         lead4 = ~ lead(., n = 4),
                         lead5 = ~ lead(., n = 5),
                         lag1 = ~ lag(., n = 1),
                         lag2 = ~ lag(., n = 2),
                         lag3 = ~ lag(., n = 3))) %>%

  mutate(start = case_when(symptom <= 2 ~ 0,
                                        symptom >= 3 ~
                                        ifelse(symptom >= lag2 & symptom <= lag1,1,0)),

         end = case_when(symptom >=3 ~ 
                                      ifelse(lead1 <=2 &
                                             lead2 <=2 &
                                             lead3 <=2 &
                                             lead4 <=2 &
                                             lead5 <=2,1,0)))
```

My main issue is that of complexity. As I build in more symptoms and rules I have to refer to different variables that have ifelse()/case_when() statements within it. I am sure there is a more elegant solution to my problem.

The other issue is that during an "exacerbation" the exacerbation_start variable should only be used at the start and not during the episode. Similarly for exacerbation_end it would only be applicable when an exacerbation is already happening. I have tried using ifelse() statements to refer to when an exacerbation is happening but not been able to get this to work and obey the rule I desire.

The output I would like is:

```
   id  day   symptom  start   end   exacerbation
1   A   1       2        0     0        0
2   A   2       2        0     0        0
3   A   3       2        0     0        0
4   A   4       2        0     0        0       
5   A   5       2        0     0        0        
6   A   6       2        0     0        0           
7   A   7       2        0     0        0          
8   A   8       2        0     0        0          
9   A   9       2        0     0        0           
10  A  10       2        0     0        0      
11  A  11       2        0     0        0          
12  A  12       3        0     0        0           
13  A  13       2        0     0        0    
14  A  14       2        0     0        0      
15  A  15       2        0     0        0          
16  A  16       2        0     0        0     
17  A  17      NA        0     0        0        
18  A  18      NA        0     0        0          
19  A  19      NA        0     0        0          
20  A  20       2        0     0        0       
21  A  21       2        0     0        0            
22  A  22       2        0     0        0       
23  A  23       3        0     0        0           
24  A  24       3        1     0        1                    
25  A  25       3        0     0        1              
26  A  26       4        0     0        1                  
27  A  27       4        0     0        1     
28  A  28       3        0     0        1          
29  A  29       3        0     0        1   
30  A  30       2        0     0        1 
31  A  31       3        0     0        1
32  A  32       2        0     0        1    
33  A  33       2        0     0        1   
34  A  34       3        0     0        1  
35  A  35       3        0     1        1  
36  A  36       2        0     0        0     
37  A  37       2        0     0        0 
38  A  38       2        0     0        0     
39  A  39       2        0     0        0  
40  A  40       2        0     0        0   
41  A  41       2        0     0        0 
42  A  42       3        0     0        0 
43  A  43       2        0     0        0
44  A  44       2        0     0        0 
45  A  45       2        0     0        0      
46  A  46       2        0     0        0   
47  A  47       2        0     0        0      
48  A  48       3        0     0        0   
49  A  49       2        0     0        0  
50  A  50       2        0     0        0
```

I look forward to your replies!

*EDIT*

I have added 50 more rows of data to simulate multiple exacerbations and the issue with right censoring and NAs. I have also included a second participant "B" to see if this is a reason for issues.

```
id <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
        "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
        "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
        "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
        "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
        "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")

day <- c(1:50,1:50)

symptom <- c(2,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,3,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,           2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,3,NA,NA,NA,3,3,3,3,3,3,2)

df <- data.frame(id,day,symptom)
```

```
     id day symptom start end   exacerbation censor
1    A   1       2     0   0            0      0
2    A   2       3     1   0            1      0
3    A   3       3     0   0            1      0
4    A   4       3     0   0            1      0
5    A   5       3     0   1            1      0
6    A   6       2     0   0            0      0
7    A   7       2     0   0            0      0
8    A   8       2     0   0            0      0
9    A   9       2     0   0            0      0
10   A  10       2     0   0            0      0
11   A  11       2     0   0            0      0
12   A  12       3     0   0            0      0
13   A  13       2     0   0            0      0
14   A  14       2     0   0            0      0
15   A  15       2     0   0            0      0
16   A  16       2     0   0            0      0
17   A  17      NA     0   0            0      0
18   A  18      NA     0   0            0      0
19   A  19      NA     0   0            0      0
20   A  20       2     0   0            0      0
21   A  21       2     0   0            0      0
22   A  22       2     0   0            0      0
23   A  23       3     1   0            1      0
24   A  24       3     0   0            1      0
25   A  25       3     0   0            1      0
26   A  26       4     0   0            1      0
27   A  27       4     0   0            1      0
28   A  28       3     0   0            1      0
29   A  29       3     0   0            1      0
30   A  30       2     0   0            1      0
31   A  31       3     0   0            1      0
32   A  32       2     0   0            1      0
33   A  33       2     0   0            1      0
34   A  34       3     0   0            1      0
35   A  35       3     0   0            1      0
36   A  36       2     0   0            1      0
37   A  37       2     0   0            1      0
38   A  38       2     0   0            1      0
39   A  39       2     0   0            1      0
40   A  40       2     0   0            1      0
41   A  41       2     0   1            1      0
42   A  42       3     0   0            0      0
43   A  43       2     0   0            0      0
44   A  44       2     0   0            0      0
45   A  45       2     0   0            0      0
46   A  46       2     0   0            0      0
47   A  47       2     0   0            0      0
48   A  48       3     0   0            0      0
49   A  49       2     0   0            0      0
50   A  50       2     0   0            0      0
51   B   1       2     0   0            0      0
52   B   2       2     0   0            0      0
53   B   3       2     0   0            0      0
54   B   4       2     0   0            0      0
55   B   5       2     0   0            0      0
56   B   6       2     0   0            0      0
57   B   7       3     0   0            0      0
58   B   8       2     0   0            0      0
59   B   9       3     0   0            0      0
60   B  10       3     1   0            1      0
61   B  11       2     0   0            1      0
62   B  12       3     0   0            1      0
63   B  13       2     0   0            1      0
64   B  14       3     0   0            1      0
65   B  15       2     0   0            1      0
66   B  16       2     0   0            1      0
67   B  17       2     0   0            1      0
68   B  18       2     0   0            1      0
69   B  19       2     0   1            1      0
70   B  20       2     0   0            0      0
71   B  21       3     1   0            1      0
72   B  22       3     0   0            1      0
73   B  23       3     0   0            1      0
74   B  24       3     0   0            1      0
75   B  25      NA     0   0            0      1
76   B  26      NA     0   0            0      1
77   B  27      NA     0   0            0      1
78   B  28       2     0   0            0      1
79   B  29       2     0   0            0      1
80   B  30       2     0   0            0      1
81   B  31       3     0   0            0      1
82   B  32       2     0   0            0      1
83   B  33       2     0   0            0      1
84   B  34       2     0   0            0      1
85   B  35       2     0   0            0      1
86   B  36       2     0   0            0      1
87   B  37       3     0   0            0      0
88   B  38       2     0   0            0      0
89   B  39       2     0   0            0      0
90   B  40       3     0   0            0      0
91   B  41      NA     0   0            0      0
92   B  42      NA     0   0            0      0
93   B  43      NA     0   0            0      0
94   B  44       3     1   0            1      0
95   B  45       3     0   0            1      0
96   B  46       3     0   0            1      0
97   B  47       3     0   0            1      0
98   B  48       3     0   0            1      0
99   B  49       3     0   0            1      0
100  B  50       2     0   0            1      0
>
```

Comment: How do you treat `NA`? E.g. what would happen if you insert at row 13 3 for the symptom?

Comment: A good question that has taken some prior thought. I plan to right censor any exacerbations with missing data. This may lead to events being loss but would reduce bias. I wouldn't know if one of the missing days had a 3 (therefore a continuation of their exacerbation) or all 2's (and subsequently an end to their exacerbation). This is another reasons why coding the "exacerbation rule" has proved difficult. The other option is to assess the symptom data manually with an independent reviewer (this is the least preferred option!) but this in itself will introduce potential bias to the analysis

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try for a more elegant and scalable way to write your algorithm:

First, you do not have to compute the `lead` and `lag` calls before you can use `case_when`. Of note, I find it good practice to explicitly write the `TRUE` option of `case_when`. Here is some code.

```
df2=df %>% 
  mutate(
    exacerbation_start = case_when(
      is.na(symptom) ~ NA_real_,
      symptom <= 2 ~ 0,
      symptom >= 3 & symptom >= lag(symptom, n=2) & symptom <= lag(symptom, n=1) ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0
    ),
    exacerbation_end = case_when(
      symptom >=3 ~ ifelse(lead(symptom, n=1) <=2 &
                             lead(symptom, n=2) <=2 & lead(symptom, n=3) <=2 &
                             lead(symptom, n=4) <=2 & lead(symptom, n=5) <=2,
                           1,0),
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
    )
  )
all.equal(df1,df2) #TRUE
```

Alternatively, if your algorithm is the same for all symptoms, you might want to use custom functions:

```
get_exacerbation_start = function(x){
  case_when( 
    is.na(x) ~ NA_real_, 
    x <= 2 ~ 0,
    x >= 3 & x >= lag(x, n=2) & x <= lag(x, n=1) ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )
}
get_exacerbation_end = function(x){
  case_when(
    x >=3 ~ ifelse(x >=3 & lead(x, n=1) <=2 & 
                     lead(x, n=2) <=2 & lead(x, n=3) <=2 & 
                     lead(x, n=4) <=2 & lead(x, n=5) <=2,
                   1,0),
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  )
}
df3=df %>% 
  mutate(
    exacerbation_start = get_exacerbation_start(symptom),
    exacerbation_end = get_exacerbation_end(symptom)
  )

all.equal(df1,df3) #also TRUE
```

This latter way might be even more powerful with some `mutate_at` calls.

**EDIT**: after seeing your edit, here is a try to get the exacerbation period. The code is quite ugly in my opinion, I'm not sure that `row_number` was supposed to be used this way.

```
df_final=df %>% 
  transmute(
    id,day,symptom, 
    start = get_exacerbation_start(symptom),
    end = get_exacerbation_end(symptom),
    exacerbation = row_number()>=which(start==1)[1] & row_number()<=which(end==1)[1]
  )
```

Comment: Secondly, for the exacerbation = row_number() >=which(start...etc, it works for the first defined exacerbation but comes up as FALSE for any exacerbations thereafter. Are there anyways around this? Maybe by ranking exacerbations from the time they occurred or by having exacerbation1, exacerbation2, exacerbation3 etc. as variables and then reorganising the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

I may come back with a less convoluted approach, but try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id,
           idx = with(
             rle(
               case_when(symptom <= 2 ~ 'normal', 
                         symptom >= 3 ~ 'worse',
                         TRUE ~ symptom %>% as.character)),
             rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)
             )
           ) %>%
  mutate(
    trajectory = case_when(cumsum(symptom <= 2) == 5 ~ 2, cumsum(symptom >= 3) == 2 ~ 1)
    ) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% fill(trajectory) %>% 
  mutate(
    trajectory = replace_na(trajectory, 0),
    start = +(trajectory == 1 & lag(trajectory) == 2),
    end = +(trajectory == 2 & lag(trajectory) == 1),
    exacerbation = +(trajectory == 1 | start == 1 | end == 1)
  ) %>% 
  select(-idx, -trajectory) %>% as.data.frame
```

Output:

```
   id day symptom start end exacerbation
1   A   1       2     0   0            0
2   A   2       2     0   0            0
3   A   3       2     0   0            0
4   A   4       2     0   0            0
5   A   5       2     0   0            0
6   A   6       2     0   0            0
7   A   7       2     0   0            0
8   A   8       2     0   0            0
9   A   9       2     0   0            0
10  A  10       2     0   0            0
11  A  11       2     0   0            0
12  A  12       3     0   0            0
13  A  13       2     0   0            0
14  A  14       2     0   0            0
15  A  15       2     0   0            0
16  A  16       2     0   0            0
17  A  17      NA     0   0            0
18  A  18      NA     0   0            0
19  A  19      NA     0   0            0
20  A  20       2     0   0            0
21  A  21       2     0   0            0
22  A  22       2     0   0            0
23  A  23       3     0   0            0
24  A  24       3     1   0            1
25  A  25       3     0   0            1
26  A  26       4     0   0            1
27  A  27       4     0   0            1
28  A  28       3     0   0            1
29  A  29       3     0   0            1
30  A  30       2     0   0            1
31  A  31       3     0   0            1
32  A  32       2     0   0            1
33  A  33       2     0   0            1
34  A  34       3     0   0            1
35  A  35       3     0   0            1
36  A  36       2     0   0            1
37  A  37       2     0   0            1
38  A  38       2     0   0            1
39  A  39       2     0   0            1
40  A  40       2     0   1            1
41  A  41       2     0   0            0
42  A  42       3     0   0            0
43  A  43       2     0   0            0
44  A  44       2     0   0            0
45  A  45       2     0   0            0
46  A  46       2     0   0            0
47  A  47       2     0   0            0
48  A  48       3     0   0            0
49  A  49       2     0   0            0
50  A  50       2     0   0            0
```

Comment: 1) How could I right censor any data after 3 consecutive NAs until the "end" rule is met i.e 5 consecutive <=  2.

Comment: 2) On a couple of examples the start rule did not pick up exacerbations starting immediately (within the first few rows). Is there a way to add a condition that if there is no prior data then to assume <=2
3) There are a few times when "end" is recognised before a start happened. Can end be conditioned to not occur before a start if there is no prior data?

I appreciate there are a lot of questions so any input would be great.

Comment: just making sure you have seen I have updated the data. Any help is massively appreciated.